# Как разбить ссылку на слова и получить их список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, python-2.x

Есть задача, раскладывать ссылки по словам в цикле по слешу. Например, есть ссылка:

```
https://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/123.jpg
```

Должен получиться список такого вида:

```
['https:','site.ru','wp-content','uploads','2016', '07', '123.jpg']
```

Как лучше всего добиться такого результата?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

самый простой, но далеко не самый лучший вариант:

```
In [45]: url = 'https://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/123.jpg'

In [46]: words = url.split('/')

In [47]: print(words)
['https:', '', 'site.ru', 'wp-content', 'uploads', '2016', '07', '123.jpg']
```

если надо избавиться от `''`:

```
In [48]: words = [x for x in url.split('/') if x]

In [49]: print(words)
['https:', 'site.ru', 'wp-content', 'uploads', '2016', '07', '123.jpg']
```

Но лучше воспользоваться специальным инструментом: [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

Comment: Чем он не лучший?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ну например он не разобъет на слова параметры, разделенные `?`, `&`

Comment: а хотят по слешу, не по прочим символам.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я подозреваю, что этот вопрос возникнет чуть позже... ;)

Comment: А он решится чуть иначе ;-)

Comment: Что то он мне так полную ссылку и возвращает, а не список.

Comment: re.split('/', url)